# How to select different columns with sequential letter+number in R?

Tags: r

I am very new in R and I need some advice about very basic issues.
I want to create a new column that is the sum of existent columns in my data frame `Data4`
The extended code is this:

```
Data4$E<-(Data4$E1+Data4$E2+Data4$E3+Data4$E4+Data4$E5)
```

I would like to simplify the code and find a way to not write the sequence of the column's name every time.
I tried this, but it indeed wrong

```
Data4$E<-(Data4$E[1:5])
```

Do you know a way to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use functions like `sum` or `rowSums`. It seems you want row sums. These functions are better than `+` because they have `na.rm` argument that controls wether or not NAs are ignored.

```
Data4$E <- rowSums(Data[, c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

An easy way to generate column names is to paste them with numbers. Equivalently, we could write it so we can reuse this for other such operations:

```
E_col_names <- sprintf("E%d", 1:5)
Data4$E <- rowSums(Data[, E_col_names], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am happy it helped and that you chose to learn R. It is an increasingly popular language with many ever-evolving ecosystems. If the answer helped you consider accepting it and/or upvoting the ones that did help you.

Answer (score 2):

Among your options are:

```
set.seed(12)
Data4 <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(5, 10, 1)))
colnames(Data4) <- paste0("E", 1:5)

# base R
Data4$E <- rowSums(Data4) # if there are just columns E1 to E5
Data4$E_option2 <- rowSums(subset(Data4, select = paste0("E", 1:5))) # if there are other columns ..

# "tidy"
library(tidyverse)

Data4 <- Data4 %>%
  mutate(E_option3 = pmap_dbl(Data4 %>%
                                select(E1:E5),
                              sum))
           
#        E1        E2        E3        E4        E5        E E_option2 E_option3
#1  8.519432  9.727704  9.222280  9.296536 10.223641 46.98959  46.98959  46.98959
#2 11.577169  9.684651  8.706118 11.188879 12.007201 53.16402  53.16402  53.16402
#3  9.043256  9.371745  9.220433 10.340512 11.011979 48.98793  48.98793  48.98793
#4  9.079995  9.893536 10.011952 10.506968  9.697541 49.18999  49.18999  49.18999
#5  8.002358 10.428015  9.847584  9.706695  8.974755 46.95941  46.95941  46.95941
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it in `dplyr` demonstrating it on `toy_data` created in one of the above answers.  Just use `E1:E5` inside `c_across`.  Of course you may also use select helper functions e.g. `starts_with` here

```r
#toy_data
set.seed(12)
Data4 <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(5, 10, 1)))
colnames(Data4) <- paste0("E", 1:5)

library(dplyr)

Data4 %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(E = sum(c_across(E1:E5)))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      E1    E2    E3    E4    E5     E
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  8.52  9.73  9.22  9.30 10.2   47.0
#> 2 11.6   9.68  8.71 11.2  12.0   53.2
#> 3  9.04  9.37  9.22 10.3  11.0   49.0
#> 4  9.08  9.89 10.0  10.5   9.70  49.2
#> 5  8.00 10.4   9.85  9.71  8.97  47.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>